# Getting the type of mobile phone

Tags: php, mobile-phones

Is there a way to get the type of mobile Phone when a phone connects to a mobi site using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the user agent with PHP, and this might give you a clue.

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/ <- Free function to read read the user agent with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). It can match all 28000something different user-agent headers to a specific mobile phone and give you it's attributes (sreenwidht/screenheight/canplayvideo/etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think your only way is to parse the user agent HTTP header. You'll get that information in the global variable $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].
See
http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/p/http_user_agent.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is a working draft from de W3C called [Device Description Repository Simple API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-DDR-Simple-API-20080404/). 
There is a [DDR Service](http://forge.morfeo-project.org/wiki_en/index.php/MyMobileWeb_Getting_Started_4.0#Step_2._Install_the_DDR_REST_Service_1.2), a reference implementation that can work with WURFL, DeviceAtlas, and UAProf under the hood.