# How to get mobile, ipad, or tablet model

Tags: php, ipad, mobile, user-agent

I want to get the mobile model, e.g iPhone 3G or 3GS, Nokia 9231, iPad Mini, Samsung tablet 10.1 etc

I used

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

but it only returns me

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
```

I also used [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) class, it only tells me the Operating system version but not telling me the device model?

**Is it possible, how?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the type of mobile phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686000/getting-the-type-of-mobile-phone)

Comment: I haven't studiously examined the MObile Detect class but there is a match() method that does a preg_match on variable $phoneDevices. Try tinker a little bit with it. Change preg_match to preg_grep to return the found match in the $phoneDevices. I only glanced at it, but if I decide to try it out in upcoming days, this question goes into my bookmarks and I'll answer it here.

Comment: @MarioLegenda but $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] don't tell us the mobile model then how can we get it using any of preg_match?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you need to do it in php. But there's a simple way of doing it in javascript.

```
alert(navigator.userAgent);
```

And you can do stuff like:

```
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    //Change some css or something like that
}
```